# CSS hover over element A but css effects on element B

Tags: css

I have an element of class B which has the below css

> .B{ display:none; }

and an element of class A which has the below css when hover over

> A:hover .B{ display:block; }

the css effect which i want to achieve is that when hover over element of class A, element of class B will appear. Is this correct? Currently its not giving me what I want. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You have two options to reach your aim. Option one is that B is a child of A. Then your css would work as expected. The other option would be if A and B are siblings, but than you need to modify your CSS a bit.

Comment: it would help if you showed us the HTML you've got, as it will help us understand where you're going wrong and thus to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your css should work.

But if .B is the only element inside .A, the visible size of .A might be 0px x 0px.

This means the :hover pseudo class will never get triggered.

You could force the size of .a with css, or by adding an invisible element inside it to stretch its size.

Answer (score 0):

CSS won't allow you to do this for arbitrary elements of the DOM tree. You will have to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: This is not true. CSS is capable of such functionality.

Comment: you could use the + selector

Comment: guess i learned something today. But still, as i said. CSS won't do it for *arbitrary* elements of the DOM tree. The + selector is called "adjacent" and doesn't allow you to select "any" element. :)

Comment: There's also the `~` selector, which means they don't even have to be adjacent. But they do still have to be siblings. There's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

It will work just if `.B` class is child of `.A` class.

Example here it works http://tinkerbin.com/V7ELzMRM because `.B` is child of `.A` and here http://tinkerbin.com/EhEYIlJL it is not working because `.B` is not child of `.A`.

Working demo: http://tinkerbin.com/V7ELzMRM

Answer (score 0):

this only works if .B is nested in .A or if its next to it in the DOM you can try:

```
.A:hover + .B {
   display:block;
}
```

you can test this here: http://cssdesk.com/Mwzzv

if its not you will need to use some JS (jQuery in this case)

```
$(".A").hover(function(){ $(".B").show() },function(){ $(".B").hide() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css is absolutely correct but for that remember the following HTML should be there to work your css properly

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
  </div>
</div>
```

If your Html is not same as above then go with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery:

```
$(documnet).ready(function(){
  $(".A").hover(function(){
    $(".B").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

or you can use this:

```
$(documnet).ready(function(){
  $(".A").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".B").css("display", "block");
  });

$(".A").mouseleave(function(){
  $(".B").css("display", "none");
   });
});
```

Comment: `.hover()` takes two arguments

Comment: document was mispelled